# Can I create two ingress in Docker Swarm?

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-swarm

When I run docker host in swarm mode automatically an ingress network is created, now my question is that can I create second ingress network as well with some command or can I create multiple ingress network ?

Comment: The ingress network is internal to swarm, why do you need a second ingress network?

Comment: If I create a new overlay network that will not be ingress in nature am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

The ingress network is internally used by docker swarm to route external traffic on a published port to your services running inside the cluster. You do not configure your services to use this network directly, instead you just publish a port and docker handles the rest.

For communication between your services, that needs to be done with a user defined overlay network. With a compose file and a `docker stack deploy` command, this is done by default. Without a compose file, you would create a network with the overlay driver, e.g. `docker network create -d overlay appnet` and then connect your services to that network. To isolate services from each other, you would add them to separate overlay networks (note the ingress network does not allow communication between services, it is strictly for north/south traffic in networking terms).

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. So if I create new overlay to isolate services then by-default the ingress will be applied to the new overlay ?

Comment: @PoojaBhatia the ingress network is separate and you don't touch it. You don't attach networks to each other, they each work as independent islands. Containers can be connected to multiple networks (like a Linux host with multiple NICs).